# How to run Mineraft on IPv6

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I would like to run Minecraft on IPv6 to simplify my life by not having to portforward every time I host a LAN server.

Also, it appears to me that even when I do forcefully run Minecraft on IPv6 by simply disabling IPv4 no computers can connect to my game over LAN.

Comment: Why do you think that moving to IPv6 protocol will defeat purpose of portforwarding? If you don't want people to connect to your LAN game, why not just create white-listed server?

Comment: @LittleHelper Because the IPv6 pool is so big ever computer gets their own external IPv6 address. I can confirm this by remotely pinging my computer which is behind a router with no portforwarding. In fact, our router doesn't even have an option to port forward IPv6.

Comment: Thanks for the tip didn't know that. You should set-up a server with different port than default or enable white-list so that nobody will be able to enter your server if they get your IP.

Comment: Do you have ipv6 available from end-to-end, meaning from your computer, through your ISPs to the guy trying to connect?

Comment: @Maerlyn Yup. The problem is minecraft doesn't want to run on IPv6...

Comment: Googling suggests that you can use ipv6, but only if you use hostnames (like adding an entry in your hosts file). Did you try that?

Comment: @Maerlyn I'll have a search on how to do that in Windows.

Comment: There's a file named hosts somewhere under c:\windows, you'll need to edit that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, as of 1.12.2, IPv6 is not supported. You'll have to get along with IPv4, but it might be possible to modify the game to support it, although vanilla clients could not connect.